# "File ended while scanning use of \math@egroup" error

Tags: errors, compiling

The error mentioned above is preventing me from compiling my code. Here's what I think is the related code:

```
    \begin{enumerate}

    \item[\textbf{5.9}]``To every pair $A, B$  of vector spaces one can assign the vector space $Hom(A,B)$ consisting for all homomorphisms from $A$ to $B$. If $f: A_1 \rightarrow A_2$ and $g: B_1 \rightarrow B_2$ are morphisms in $\mathbf{Vec_{\mathbb{R}}$, then the vector space homomorphism $Hom(f,g): Hom(A_2, B_1) \rightarrow Hom(A_1, B_2)$ is given by $\phi \mapsto g \circ \phi \circ f$." \vspace{11pt}\\

    \end{enumerate}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I tried moving the code to a different .tex file but the same error occurred, so I don't think the error is specific to the file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet compilable ...

Comment: That's still not a full document, which would begin with `\documentclass{...}`, include the necessary packages and have a `\begin{document} ... \end{document}` environment... Anyway, there is a closing brace missing in `$\mathbf{Vec_{\mathbb{R}}$`, which is probably the source of the error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a trivial syntax mistake that was solved in the comments.

Comment: @diabonas yes sorry I'd answered while you were commenting:-) But to make an answer more or less worth while I expanded it to show how to read the error message to locate the error. But if people vote to close that's OK too:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No problem, +1 to your answer, just wanting to make sure the question gets off the unanswered list ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$\mathbf{Vec_{\mathbb{R}}$
```

is missing a `}`

Note the full error message which you did not show highlights the mis-matched brace:

```
Runaway argument?
{Vec_{\mathbb {R}}$, then the vector space homomorphism $Hom(f,g): Ho\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \math@egroup.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> pp565

?
```

The runaway argument messages shows you that the brace `{` before `Vec` doesn't have a matching `}` and tex ran off the end of the file looking for it.

unrelated but `Vec` and `Hom` will be typeset in math italic designed to make them look like V * e * c not as a word. use

```
\DeclareMathOperator\Vec{Vec}
```

then use `\Vec` to get much better spacing.

Comment: Wow, there are LOTS of "File ended while scanning…" questions here! If only we could re-write this error message :)